# PHP RegEx to remove all Checkboxes

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use `preg_replace` to remove all checkboxes from a variable of HTML. This is what I'm using now:

```
echo preg_replace('/<input type="checkbox".*autocomplete="off">/', '', $html);
```

To replace checkboxes like the following:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="65[]" id="289" value="289" validate="required:true" autocomplete="off"> a.  date of encounter</label>
```

This doesn't work at all. If I change the regex to:

```
<input type="checkbox".*">
```

It then works but removes too much.

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML.  Use a proper HTML parsing module.** You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: The HTML that I'm parsing won't change as I made the code that outputs it. Regex is what I need, thanks though.

Comment: If you made the code that output the HTML, why not change the code that outputs it to not output the HTML that you're trying to eliminate?

Comment: Giving comments on your opinion is not what I asked, this is a Q&A forum not a regular forum for opinions. I asked a question not for opinions. The code that outputs the checkboxes is a huge function for another page, to make it filter for this one single page would take hours of work to make sure I don't break the previous page. This regex has taken 20 minutes. Thanks.

Comment: @AndyLester For a one-off situation like this I would definitely just use regex. Obviously if you are trying to manipulate several things in the DOM, a parser should be used (as in most cases) but here he just needs something quick and simple.

Comment: @jfreak53: I understand it's not what you asked, but sometimes it's possible that others see solutions that you might not have considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/<input type="checkbox"(.+?)autocomplete="off">/is', '', $html);
```

Comment: To be clear to future readers, the `(.*)` in the original question is a greedy match that matches the longest string possible.  Adding `?` makes it a non-greedy or parsimonious match that matches the shortest pattern possible.  Also, note that this answer changes the 0-or-more of `*` to the 1-or-more of `+`.